# How do I get the input from a textfield in a netbeans RCP app?

Tags: java

I am making a text based game in Java. I have a text field, enter button, and a label.

What code do i use to scan the text field once the button is clicked and respond?

So that if I type in (launch missile) the label should say (missile launched).

I will be listening to a button `actionperformed` or maybe a mouseclick event . Something like this

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
if (Text field says: launch missile)
   {print on label:Missile launched}
```

or

```
if (text field says: invade)
   {Print on label: Invasion started}
```

Comment: Why this is getting down voted? No newbie questions here??

Comment: The title of the question could be more descriptive, like "how do I get the input from a textfield in a netbeans rcp app?"
Also it would help if you would format your code (e.g. proper indentation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can read the text field using

```
 textField1.getText()
```

to compare, use

```
 if (textField1.getText().equals("launch missle"))
 {
     //do something
 }
```

similarly, to set the label's text, use

```
label1.setText("Missle launched");
```

I suggest reading more about [Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) [flow](http://home.cogeco.ca/~ve3ll/jatutor3.htm) [control](http://www.learn-java-tutorial.com/Comparisons-And-Control.cfm).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
JButton launch=new JButton(new AbstractAction("Launch")
    {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
         {
         yourLabel.setText("Missile Launched");
         }
    });
```